# How to convert a vector<string> to null terminated char **?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a `std::vector<std::string>` to a NULL terminated array of C-style strings (`char *`). Is it possible without copying with `new`/`malloc`?

Basically, I want to convert vec back into the EXACT SAME thing as arr without new/malloc.

```c
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void print(const char **strs)
{
   const char **ptr = strs;
   while(*ptr) {
      printf("%s ", *ptr);
      ++ptr;
   }
}

void print(std::vector<std::string> &strs) {
   for(auto iter = strs.begin(); iter != strs.end(); ++iter) {
      printf("%s ", iter->c_str());
   }
}

void main()
{
   const char *arr[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", NULL };

   vector<string> vec;

   const char **str = arr;
   while(*str) {
      vec.push_back(*str);
      ++str;
   }
   vec.push_back((char *) NULL); //Doesn't work

   //print(vec);
   print((const char **) &vec[0]);
}
```

Comment: You ask one thing but your code is trying to do something completely different. What is the actual question?

Comment: No. It is not possible without malloc because a std::string is a pointer. So the set of strings you have in your vector are not right to each other at the memory.

Comment: `std::string::c_str()` will return a c-style string.

Comment: I realize that std::vector contains more than a char *, it also contains the size. However, each element in the vector SHOULD be a char *. I'm just confused why this solution segfaults.

Comment: @user2254018 Is your question is to convert `vector<string>` to `vector<char*>` ?

Comment: I'm trying to convert "vec" in the example to a NULL terminated char ** without the use of new[char *] and setting each element to its respective str.c_str().

Comment: @user2254018 But `str.c_str()` returns a `const char*` and not `char**`. You can allocate array of pointers of size of the vector and assign them with `str.c_str()` while iterating over the vector.

Comment: Isn't that still possible using a temporary vector and c_str() results as lvalue references?

Comment: @AndréPuel: A `std::string` is absolutely not "a pointer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible just by setting a pointer to the beginning of that vector, because `vector<string>` is not sequential characters as you expect.

```
                   addr1   addr2    addr3
                    ^        ^        ^
                    |        |        |
                +--------+--------+--------+----
                |   |    |   |    |   |    |
                |  std:: |  std:: |  std:: |
       +---->   | string | string | string | ...
       |        |        |        |        |
       |        +--------+--------+--------+----
       |
       |
       |
 vector<string>
```

`addr1`, `addr2` and `addr3` are random addresses in memory.

So, the solution is iterating over the items, read the strings and characters and put them in your continues array.

Comment: Isn't vector itself contiguous, though? I understand that the strings might not be... which could be the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I get it... basically vector<string> is really char *** where each vec[index] is a char ** + int for size.

Comment: @user2254018: The vector manages a contiguous array of string objects, each of which manages a contiguous array of characters. But the string object is not (just) `char*`, and the vector is not (just) `string*`, so there is no way to get an array of `char*` without building one yourself.

Comment: "It's not possible" - aham, sure, what did I just do then?

Comment: @H2CO3: I mean he can just not set a pointer to beginning of the vector and simply use it as `**`.

Comment: @MM. Yes, that's true. Still, a "conversion" between two objects of the datatypes is certainly doable.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to build the array of pointers yourself, and you will need dynamic allocation if the size isn't known at compile time. (In this example, you could infer it from `sizeof arr`; but I'm assuming that `arr` isn't available when you need to reconstruct it).

You *can* use pointers to the strings managed by the vector, so you won't need to allocate any memory for them.

So you can get the array you need thusly:

```
std::vector<char const *> vec2;
vec2.reserve(vec.size()+1); // optional, but might improve efficiency
for (auto const & str : vec) {
    vec2.push_back(str.c_str());
}
vec2.push_back(nullptr);

print(vec.data());
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I implemented. Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible without copying with new/malloc?

If your C++ compiler supports variable-length arrays as an extension, then it is. Else you will have to use dynamic memory allocation.

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
// initialize `vec', etc.

const char *c_strings[vec.size()];
size_t idx = 0;
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
    c_strings[idx++] = it->c_str();
}
```

Comment: Just a side note -- it is legal for a C compiler to implement VLA:s in terms of dynamic memory allocation...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you can't store a "NULL" inside a `std::vector<std::string>`, which I think is what you are aiming to do.

The whole point with `std::vector` is that it keeps track of number of entries in `std::vector::size()`

However, if you really need to have a something that you can pass to a function like your print, then you could do something like this:

```
vector<const char *> v;

for(auto iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter) {
   v.push_back(iter->c_str());
}
v.push_back(NULL);

print(&v[0]);
```

Comment: Not what I wanted. If specifics are needed... I'm making a wrapper around this function. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTransformFeedbackVaryings.xml

Comment: I've now added a "NULL" push-back, which should work for your purposes. If it doesn't, can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: I wanted a solution that used the same vector and just appended a NULL to the end without creating a new one. What your doing is essentially the same thing as new.

Comment: Ok, then I don't have a solution for you. And I doubt there is one.